# Is it possible to connect Android tablets without onboard GPS to a GPSd server for location data?

Tags: android, location, android-gps, gpsd

I have a working GPSd server (Raspberry Pi) with an external GPS receiver providing high quality GPS.

I have tested and can connect to it remotely from other machines across a standard wifi/cabled ethernet link.  The GPSd server is working perfectly well.

I want to use Android tablets that do not have an onboard GPS receiver  to use this GPSd server as a position source.   These Android tablets would be on the same wifi network as the GPSd server.

To my mind this should be simple but I do not know or cannot find an app to point an Android tablet at a GPSd client.

Am I looking for the impossible here ?

Many thanks.

1. Tried a bunch of apps in the store.  Most of them are about forwarding the Android Phone's GPS somewhere else.